# WPF: put Label around Circle in specific Circle Value point

Tags: wpf, geometry

So i have this `Circle` and `Slider`:

```
<DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar
    x:Name="circle"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Percentage="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"
    SegmentColor="Red"
    StrokeThickness="25"
    Radius="100"/>
```

So when this `Slider` value changed My `Circle` `Percentage` property is updated but also i want to add `Label` near the `Circle` `Value`.

For example if the `Circle` `Percentage` is `83%` i want:

[image]

So inside my `Slider` ValueChanged `Event` i calculate this:

```
    public void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        var radius = circle.Radius;
        var sangle = (slider.Value * 360) / 100;
        double angleRad = (Math.PI / 180.0) * (sangle - 90);

        double x = radius * Math.Cos(angleRad);
        double y = radius * Math.Sin(angleRad);

        vlb.Content = string.Format("{0:N2}", slider.Value);
        vlb.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform { Angle = sangle, CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0 };
    }
```

So i create simple `Label`:

```
    <Label x:Name="vlb"
           Content="123"
       Margin="-50,-50,-50,-50"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
       Grid.RowSpan="2"
       xml:space="preserve">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform/>
        <SkewTransform/>
        <RotateTransform Angle="3600.12"/>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Label.RenderTransform>  
    </Label>
```

And the result is almost what i want:

[image]

The only problem is that my `Label` is not straight.

Any suggestions how to solve it ?

Comment: Unrelated, but won't it be more clear to just put percentage in the center of the circle?

Comment: Yes this decently easier, but i think this should much nicer

Comment: I personally think putting it at center will be much nicer, compared to a label running around the circle (quite annoying). Anyway as for your question - put your progress bar together with label inside Canvas then set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties of your label, I think that should work.

Comment: Ok so i almost there, please see my update